# Targeting location and marking locations in Google Map using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-maps

I know such questions are already asked on SO many times, but my scenario is slight different. What I want is ,
I have 10 book store address of South Boston. Now I want to display those 10 Book Store on the Google map within a circle over the South Boston.

See the image below. It should be developed in ASP.Net/C# - 3.5/4.0 , I would prefer if some managed code will be available for the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare a new [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object
2. Loop through the bookstore locations and use the bound's `extend` method to include all locations in the bound.
3. Get the northeast and southwest point lat-lng of the bound using `getNorthEast` and `getSouthWest` method.
4. Get distance between northeast and southwest using `computeDistanceBetween` method of [geometry.spherical](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)
5. Divide the distance by 2 to get circle radius.
6. Use `getCenter` method of the bound to get center of the circle.
7. Use above radius and center to draw the circle.

Answer (score 0):

well you can draw a circle with center at some point and radius provided using google maps APIV3. for demo visit  [Google Maps OverLays.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Circles)

if you want to show all the markers in the circle then create some logic and set the radius of the circle, in your case it will depend on the position of the book stores on the map. so create a logic and process the positions of your book stores and then set center and radius of circle as according.